# Using cat in conky_parse doesn't work

Tags: cat, conky

I'm trying to show the name of my shell in conky. I can capture the name of the shell using this command:

```
cat /proc/$$/comm
```

But when I use this in my `script.lua` file, like this:

```
text = 'Shell: ' .. conky_parse('${execi 3600 cat /proc/$$/comm}')
```

It only shows the word `cat`:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to an optimisation done by the shell. Your code will eventually run

```
sh -c 'cat /proc/$$/comm'
```

and the shell will expand the `$$` to the shell's pid, then decide that since there are no more commands to do, it will `exec()` the `cat` rather than forking to exec and waiting for the child.

You can see this if you run the above command, which replies `cat`. But if you add another command, eg

```
sh -c 'cat /proc/$$/comm; echo $$'
```

you will see `sh` and the second command.  A quick fix is to use `<` to make the shell open the proc file before running cat:

```
'${execi 3600 cat </proc/$$/comm}'
```

If you want to see the difference, use `strace -f -o /tmp/trace sh -c '...'` and look through the trace output.

---

Unfortunately, conky will alway run commands using `sh` rather than any  `SHELL` value you may have set in the environment.  So you will always find `sh` unless it is a link to some other shell, such as `bash`. The easy answer is to:

```
 ${execi 3600 echo $SHELL}
```

or if you need to really execute the shell then:

```
 ${execi 3600 exec $SHELL -c 'cat /proc/$$/comm;echo -n'}
```

Comment: Using `cat < /proc/$$/comm` will print `sh`, but my shell is `zsh`.

Comment: It seems conky always runs sh. See my update.

Comment: This works, but I can manually change the value of `$SHELL`, for example like `SHELL="bash"`, to something else and the behavior changes. So I guess it doesn't differ from using `$(execi 3600 echo $SHELL)`.